# yii2 application configuration location path

Tags: php, configuration, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to add this code to application configuration, i got it from this  *[link](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin/blob/master/docs/guide/configuration.md)*.

```
return [
'modules' => [
    'admin' => [
        'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module',
        ...
    ]
    ...
],
...
'components' => [
    ...
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager', // or use 'yii\rbac\DbManager'
    ]
],
'as access' => [
    'class' => 'mdm\admin\components\AccessControl',
    'allowActions' => [
        'site/*',
        'admin/*',
        'some-controller/some-action',
        // The actions listed here will be allowed to everyone including guests.
        // So, 'admin/*' should not appear here in the production, of course.
        // But in the earlier stages of your development, you may probably want to
        // add a lot of actions here until you finally completed setting up rbac,
        // otherwise you may not even take a first step.
    ]
],];
```

But where's that file located?
I'm using Yii2 Advanced template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add this inside your configuration main file which is located in backend and frontend (depending on your requirement).

**in Backend**

```
Path : backend/config/main.php
```

**and in frontend**

```
Path : frontend/config/main.php
```

you must add all configuration settings in respective components

Comment: No, i have not used it yet..you can post your seperate question .. all are ready to help here..

Comment: Glad to hear that :D I hope you can solve this error too just like another problem :D, this is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674952/error-when-trying-to-load-dual-listbox-in-yii2) :)